# Manage null in stream none match

Tags: java

I try to use stream to manage dto to bean.

```
List<CarDto> carsDto = dto.getCars();
List<Cars> cars = bean.getCars();

for (Cars car : cars) {

    if (carsDto==null || carsDto.stream().noneMatch(c -> c.getId().intValue() == car.getId())) {
        bean.removeCars(car);
    }

}
```

actually when element of carsDto is null, i get null pointer exception.

when element is null, I would like to do

```
bean.removeCars(car);
```

Comment: So.. what is the exception?

Comment: What do you actually want to do when a `carDto` is `null`? There's many ways to avoid the error, but they will lead to different results.

Comment: answer to your question is alreay in the post.

Comment: Indeed, sorry...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A stacktrace or some code about the classes would be quite helpful. My bet is the NPE occurs in the line containing `if` and comes from a `null` being casted to a primitive `int` in one of these two:

```
c.getId()   // returns null or
car.getId() // returns null
```

If the NPE doesn't come from one of these, then `dto.getCars()` might return a `List` with `null` values or `bean.removeCars(car)` throws an NPE...

Answer (score 1):

Neither `Stream.allMatch`, `.noneMatch`, `anyMatch` nor any reduction function that reduces to a single `boolean` can do the trick alone because while you want to remove the car when **no** dto matches the car, you want to remove it when **any** dto is `null`.

You could always use two stream pipelines if you don't mind having twice as bad performances, but I will instead suggest the following :

```
List<CarDto> carsDto = dto.getCars();
List<Cars> cars = bean.getCars();

if (carsDto == null || carsDto.stream().anyMatch(Objects::isNull)) {
    cars.forEach(car -> bean.removeCars(car)); //remove all cars when the dto list is null or contains a null dto
} else {
    cars.stream().filter(car ->                //select cars with a corresponding dto 
        carsDto.stream().anyMatch(dto ->
            car.getId() == dto.getId().intValue()
        )
    ).forEach(car -> bean.removeCars(car));    //and remove them
}
```

Comment: why c -> c == null ||   instead of  c -> c != null &&  ?

Comment: because i need to remove car when it's null or if it not found, i think only c -> c != null && is good.